# Pandas: Sampling columns based on weights

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with three columns containing probabilities:

```
Prob0 Prob1 Prob2
 0.1   0.6    0.3
 0.2   0.1    0.7
```

I need to generate a column that contains, for each row, the value 0 with probability Prob0, the value 1 with probability Prob1 and the value 2 with probability Prob2.

Alternatively, I am happy if I generate a column that contains the value Prob0 with probability Prob0, the value Prob1 with probability Prob1 and the value Prob2 with probability Prob2.

I have tried with the `sample` function, but it does not work:

```
population['ChoiceProba'] = population[['Prob0', 'Prob1', 'Prob2']].sample(weights=population[['Prob0', 'Prob1', 'Prob2']], axis=1)
```

I receive the error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have also considered the `numpy.random.choice`function, but did not manage to combine it with a `pandas`statement without a loop.
I would like to avoid a loop, as I have 1000000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got your point.

Sicne I have no information about your factors, I followed your descprition and put 0, 1 and 0.5.

Here are three options to create this:

**Using `dot()`** recommended

```
weights = [0,1,0.5]
df['ChoiceProba'] = df.dot(weights)
```

**using `sum()`**

```
weights = [0,1,0.5]
df['ChoiceProba'] = (df * weights).sum(1)
```

**using `apply()`**

```
weights = [0,1,0.5]
df['ChoiceProba'] = df.apply(lambda x: weights[0]*x['Prob0']+weights[1]*x['Prob1']+weights[2]*x['Prob2'], axis=1)
```

**Output**

The Outpur is the same for all variations:

```
   Prob0  Prob1  Prob2  ChoiceProba
0    0.1    0.6    0.3         0.75
1    0.2    0.1    0.7         0.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Your solution does not exactly addresses the problem, but it seems that using the `apply` function of `pandas`works:

```
def select(weight):
    alts = [0, 1, 2]
    weights = [weight.Prob0, weight.Prob1, weight.Prob2]
    return np.random.choice(alts, p=weights)

population['Choice'] = population.apply(select, axis=1)
```

Running time on MacBook Pro:

```
CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 4.05 µs
```

The results are as expected:

```
    Prob0       Prob1       Prob2       Choice
0   0.014909    0.709707    0.275384    1
1   0.311306    0.681123    0.007570    1
2   0.212640    0.612233    0.175128    0
3   0.269021    0.725671    0.005307    1
4   0.055383    0.861544    0.083073    1
... ... ... ... ...
999995  0.322557    0.674554    0.002889    1
999996  0.137054    0.450639    0.412307    2
999997  0.267068    0.456676    0.276256    1
999998  0.222638    0.777358    0.000003    1
999999  0.120129    0.427084    0.452787    2
```